# Need help wih references - ARC + Cocos 2d

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

ARC is kicking my ARC

I installed cocos 2d and was unhappy seeing as I wanted to use ARC. I am having an issue that I can't quite seem to figure out.

Instruments is saying I have 5 references to my GraphicsManager object, yet I can only conclude 4 of them. I need to create and release many of these.

Class "RowManager" (CCLayer) calls class "GraphicsManager" (CCNode) to make these Objects. RowManager calls its methods to move the objects via selector:
    [self schedule:@selector(row:) interval:.01]

Finally, when the object arrives at a point, method "row1Finished" is called who then creates one more reference to the object before calling the object to (die) remove it's own children.

I can get all three animations to stop, get the object to detach from the RowManager and disappear, yet the dealloc method still does not call itself. What am I doing wrong?

To convert my non-arc cocos2d template I followed the instructions here:

http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/04/enabling-arc-cocos2d-project-howto-stepbystep-tutorialguide/

```
/////////////////

@interface RowManager : CCLayer {
    GraphicsManager *graphicsObject;
}

@implementation RowManager
-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init]) ) {

        graphicsObject = [[GraphicsManager alloc] initWithBoatType:@"flatboat" withWord:@"life" usingCharacter:@"Puchai" orientation:@"up" visible:YES];
        graphicsObject.tag = 21;
        graphicsObject.position = ccp(offset,size.height/4.1);
        [self addChild: graphicsObject];
        [self schedule:@selector(row1:) interval:.01];
        [self schedule:@selector(rotate:) interval:6];

// etc…


-(void)row1:(ccTime)dt{
    // scroll the object across the screen
    graphicsObject = (GraphicsManager *)[self getChildByTag:21]; // reference: for the row method
    graphicsObject.position = ccp(graphicsObject.position.x-1, graphicsObject.position.y);
    if (graphicsObject.position.x < 0 - graphicsObject.boatWidth){
        [self row1Finished];

    }
}

-(void)rotate:(ccTime)dt {
    //waggle the object a bit
   graphicsObject = (GraphicsManager *)[self getChildByTag:21]; // reference 2: for the rotate method
    [graphicsObject runAction:[CCSequence actions:
                               [CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:1 angle:.8],
                               [CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:2 angle:-.8],
                               [CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:1 angle:-.8],
                               [CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:2 angle:.8],
                               nil]];
}
-(void) row1Finished {

    graphicsObject = (GraphicsManager *)[self getChildByTag:21]; // reference 3: to reference the referenced

    [self unschedule:@selector (row1:)];
    [self unschedule:@selector(rotateBoat:)];
    [graphicsObject die];  // call within object class to remove references
    [self removeChild:graphicsObject cleanup:YES];
    graphicsObject = nil;
}

/////////////////////

in Graphics Manager Class:

///////////////////


@interface GraphicsManager : CCNode {...}
@property CGFloat boatWidth;
…etc

@implementation GraphicsManager
@synthesize boatWidth;
- (void) die {

    [self unschedule:@selector(puchaiRow:)]; // reference 4 animation 
    [self stopAllActions];
    [self removeAllChildrenWithCleanup:YES]; // removes sub objects created in class

    NSLog(@"Died");
}
- (void)dealloc
{
    CCLOG(@"Graphics Manager dealloc: %@", self);
}

-(id)initWithBoatType:(NSString *)boatType orientation:(NSString *)orientation
{

    self = [super init];
    if (self){

        if ([orientation isEqual: @"upstream"]){

            flatBoat = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"flatBoat.png"];
            flatBoat.anchorPoint = ccp(0,0);
            self.boatWidth = [flatBoat boundingBox].size.width;
            [self addChild:flatBoat];

            [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"puchai.plist"];
            puchai = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"puchai1.png"];
            puchai.anchorPoint = ccp(0,0);
            puchai.position = ccp(20,30);
            puchai.tag = 4;
            [self addChild:puchai];

            [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"cube.plist"];


            cube = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"cube1.png"];
            cube.scale = .80;
            cube.tag = 56;
            cube.visible = NO;
            cube.position = ccp(150,45);
            [self addChild:cube];

            cube = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"cube2.png"];
            cube.scale = .80;
            cube.position = ccp(-1 +150,[cube boundingBox].size.height +45);
            cube.tag = 57;
            cube.visible = NO;
            [self addChild:cube];


           [self schedule:@selector(puchaiRow:) interval:3]; // reference 4 animation

            flatBoatWing = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"flatBoatWing.png"];
            flatBoatWing.anchorPoint = ccp(0,0);
            flatBoatWing.position = ccp(25,17);
            [self addChild:flatBoatWing];


        }
///etc

-(void)puchaiRow:(ccTime)dt{

    puchai = (CCSprite *)[self getChildByTag:4];
    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"puchai.plist"];
    NSMutableArray *frames = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (int i = 1; i<=8; i++) {

        NSString *frameName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"puchai%i.png",i ];
        [frames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]
                           spriteFrameByName:frameName]];
    }
    CCAnimation *a = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:frames delay:1.0f/5.0f];
    [puchai runAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:a]];
```

//////////
here is the zombies:history output.

```
#   Address Category    Event Type  RefCt   Timestamp   Size    Responsible Caller
0   0x13ea95e0  GraphicsManager Malloc  1   00:02.748.439   208 -[RowManager init]
1   0x13ea95e0  GraphicsManager Retain  2   00:02.748.447   0   -[GraphicsManager initWithBoatType:withWord:usingCharacter:orientation:visible:]
2   0x13ea95e0  GraphicsManager Release 1   00:02.748.449   0   -[GraphicsManager initWithBoatType:withWord:usingCharacter:orientation:visible:]
3   0x13ea95e0  GraphicsManager Retain  2   00:02.841.543   0   -[CCScheduler scheduleSelector:forTarget:interval:paused:repeat:delay:]
4   0x13ea95e0  GraphicsManager Retain  3   00:02.841.572   0   ccArrayAppendObjectWithResize
5   0x13ea95e0  GraphicsManager Retain  4   00:03.477.669   0   -[RowManager row1:]  <--- AHA!!!! 
6   0x13ea95e0  GraphicsManager Retain  5   00:03.482.438   0   -[RowManager row1Finished]
7   0x13ea95e0  GraphicsManager Release 4   00:03.482.439   0   -[RowManager row1Finished]
8   0x13ea95e0  GraphicsManager Release 3   00:03.482.480   0   -[CCScheduler removeHashElement:]
9   0x13ea95e0  GraphicsManager Release 2   00:03.483.435   0   ccArrayRemoveObjectAtIndex
10  0x13ea95e0  GraphicsManager Release 1   00:03.483.436   0   -[RowManager row1Finished]
```

Comment: Do you know about the "object history" functionality of the allocation instrument? It will tell you the line of code for every retain and release for that object and so you can tell who's holding on to it.

Comment: Thanks for the input Jesse, I was looking at the zombies version... The allocation instrument alludes to 
    Responsible Caller: [RowManager init]

So I'm guessing the RowManager init call is the object being retained. Stupid question time: how to unallocate an object after it's init is run and done? Am I not doing just that in row1Finished by assigning graphicsObject to nil?

Comment: Yes, your init method looks fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by reviewing the zombies history one more time. In row1, I did not set the object to nil after calling row1finished, breaking the law: for each reference in the same class you must "nillify" all references to zero...

Moral of the story: the reason it was difficult to find the bug was because I had scheduled the row1 routine and was letting it run about 50 times, causing a bunch of retain releases in the zombies history making it impossible to reduce by elimination.  I commented out the surrounding code getting rid of all that and was able to get a zombies output that i could parse.

Thanks all for your input! I guess I know how to use instruments a little better now!

```
-(void)row1:(ccTime)dt{

    graphicsObjectRow1 = (GraphicsManager *)[self getChildByTag:11];
    graphicsObjectRow1.position = ccp(graphicsObjectRow1.position.x + 1,graphicsObjectRow1.position.y);

   // if (graphicsObjectRow1.position.x > screenX/4){
        [self row1Finished];
    graphicsObjectRow1 = nil;
        // graphicsObjectRow1.position = ccp(offset,size.height/4.1);
   // }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `(__bridge id)` to exclude from ARC, what do you need to exclude & use manual Retain-Release.

Answer (score 0):

Should `[self unschedule:@selector (row1:)];` be `[self unschedule:@selector (row:)];`? That would keep an extra reference alive.

Comment: I pasted the code from a larger program and in the process probably made some syntax errors, like this. sorry

Comment: It's not a syntax error; if you're unscheduling a call to `row1:` instead of `row:`, it could cause exactly the problem you're seeing. Unless it was a copy-paste problem :)

Comment: well, yes that's what i meant!!